# How can i get a uniswap pool address using web3py?

Tags: web3.py

I'm trying to get the address of a uniswap pool on chain, without using any graph or api. The uniswap v3 pool abi seems to have a `getPool` method that does exactly this.
I'm using that method but for some reason i get that a specific pool doesn't exist while it exists.

Here is an example

```
from web3 import Web3

abi = [{'inputs': [], 'stateMutability': 'nonpayable', 'type': 'constructor'}, {'anonymous': False, 'inputs': [{'indexed': True, 'internalType': 'uint24', 'name': 'fee', 'type': 'uint24'}, {'indexed': True, 'internalType': 'int24', 'name': 'tickSpacing', 'type': 'int24'}], 'name': 'FeeAmountEnabled', 'type': 'event'}, {'anonymous': False, 'inputs': [{'indexed': True, 'internalType': 'address', 'name': 'oldOwner', 'type': 'address'}, {'indexed': True, 'internalType': 'address', 'name': 'newOwner', 'type': 'address'}], 'name': 'OwnerChanged', 'type': 'event'}, {'anonymous': False, 'inputs': [{'indexed': True, 'internalType': 'address', 'name': 'token0', 'type': 'address'}, {'indexed': True, 'internalType': 'address', 'name': 'token1', 'type': 'address'}, {'indexed': True, 'internalType': 'uint24', 'name': 'fee', 'type': 'uint24'}, {'indexed': False, 'internalType': 'int24', 'name': 'tickSpacing', 'type': 'int24'}, {'indexed': False, 'internalType': 'address', 'name': 'pool', 'type': 'address'}], 'name': 'PoolCreated', 'type': 'event'}, {'inputs': [{'internalType': 'address', 'name': 'tokenA', 'type': 'address'}, {'internalType': 'address', 'name': 'tokenB', 'type': 'address'}, {'internalType': 'uint24', 'name': 'fee', 'type': 'uint24'}], 'name': 'createPool', 'outputs': [{'internalType': 'address', 'name': 'pool', 'type': 'address'}], 'stateMutability': 'nonpayable', 'type': 'function'}, {'inputs': [{'internalType': 'uint24', 'name': 'fee', 'type': 'uint24'}, {'internalType': 'int24', 'name': 'tickSpacing', 'type': 'int24'}], 'name': 'enableFeeAmount', 'outputs': [], 'stateMutability': 'nonpayable', 'type': 'function'}, {'inputs': [{'internalType': 'uint24', 'name': '', 'type': 'uint24'}], 'name': 'feeAmountTickSpacing', 'outputs': [{'internalType': 'int24', 'name': '', 'type': 'int24'}], 'stateMutability': 'view', 'type': 'function'}, {'inputs': [{'internalType': 'address', 'name': '', 'type': 'address'}, {'internalType': 'address', 'name': '', 'type': 'address'}, {'internalType': 'uint24', 'name': '', 'type': 'uint24'}], 'name': 'getPool', 'outputs': [{'internalType': 'address', 'name': '', 'type': 'address'}], 'stateMutability': 'view', 'type': 'function'}, {'inputs': [], 'name': 'owner', 'outputs': [{'internalType': 'address', 'name': '', 'type': 'address'}], 'stateMutability': 'view', 'type': 'function'}, {'inputs': [], 'name': 'parameters', 'outputs': [{'internalType': 'address', 'name': 'factory', 'type': 'address'}, {'internalType': 'address', 'name': 'token0', 'type': 'address'}, {'internalType': 'address', 'name': 'token1', 'type': 'address'}, {'internalType': 'uint24', 'name': 'fee', 'type': 'uint24'}, {'internalType': 'int24', 'name': 'tickSpacing', 'type': 'int24'}], 'stateMutability': 'view', 'type': 'function'}, {'inputs': [{'internalType': 'address', 'name': '_owner', 'type': 'address'}], 'name': 'setOwner', 'outputs': [], 'stateMutability': 'nonpayable', 'type': 'function'}]

uni_v3_pool = '0x1F98431c8aD98523631AE4a59f267346ea31F984'

Infura_HTTP = '<MY-PROVIDER>'
w3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(Infura_HTTP))

univ3 = w3.eth.contract(uni_v3_pool, abi=abi)

eth = "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
cvx = '0x4e3FBD56CD56c3e72c1403e103b45Db9da5B9D2B'

print(univ3.functions.getPool(cvx, eth, 3000).call())
```

This code returns `0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000`, which means that the CVX-ETH pool doesn't exist, but according to Etherscan the pool exists: https://etherscan.io/address/0x2e4784446a0a06df3d1a040b03e1680ee266c35a. Why is that? Am i doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method `UniswapV3Factory.getPool(address tokenA, address tokenB, uint24 fee)` returns the pool address of a given pair, given the pair token addresses and the pool's fee parameter.

The problem with your query above is that you've assigned eth the `0` address, but the correct way would be to assign it the mainnet [WETH contract](https://etherscan.io/address/0xc02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2) address which is `0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2`. As any ETH pair is actually realized with the WETH (Wrapped ETH) token.

As for the fee, if you want `getPool(...)` to return the pool address `0x2e4784446a0a06df3d1a040b03e1680ee266c35a`, then the fee parameter should be `10000` as that's the pool fee as can be seen in the [pool contract's storage](https://etherscan.io/address/0x2e4784446a0a06df3d1a040b03e1680ee266c35a#readContract). You could also try other different fee tiers to get different pools, while keeping the pool token pair tokens intact.

Comment: Thanks a lot! If i change the fee from 3000 to 10000 it will work. One last question: how do i know in advance which fee to use? Or do i need ot use 10000 for all of them?

Comment: You would need to try out different fees to find all the different pair pools. Uniswap V3 only has a few fee tiers (0.05%, 0.3% and 1%), so that should make it easier.